# cross domain access-control-allow-origin error

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to access a web service but getting cross domain access-control-allow-origin error

```
$.getJSON("https://beevou.net/oauth/token?grant_type=password&username="+user+
 "&password="+pass+"&client_id=NTEzZGU5MThlNDQ0YWM0&client_secret=45d1002085db5dca4dbdbc5f83731     d19662cb265",
 function(data) {
 console.log(JSON.stringify(data)); 
});
```

This is the url. Cant change anything at web service side.
Let me know some solution to get rid of this problem

thanks in advance

Comment: possible duplicate of [Ways to circumvent the same-origin policy](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3076414/ways-to-circumvent-the-same-origin-policy)

Comment: @Quentin nice link, I bookmark it

Answer (score 1):

Basically, if you can't get a JSONP access or obtain from the server they set the necessary CORS headers, the only possible solutions are on your server :

- issue the request on your server and serve the result for your page
- set up a proxy on your server to let the browser think everything comes from the same origin (this is the easiest solution, for example with [mod_proxy](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_proxy.html#forwardreverse) if your server is Apache based)

Answer (score 0):

Can you get a result if you change the dataType to JSONP? Like:

```
$.ajax({
    dataType: 'jsonp', 
    url: "https://beevou.net/oauth/token?grant_type=password&username="+user+
 "&password="+pass+"&client_id=NTEzZGU5MThlNDQ0YWM0&client_secret=45d1002085db5dca4dbdbc5f83731     d19662cb2652",
    success: function(data) {
        console.log(data);
    },
    error: function() {
        alert('nok');
    }
});
```